# Error using subcaption

Tags: captions, subfloats

I've used the subcaption package in the past without any problem. But now, i can't use it, which makes it impossible to compile some important documents.

If i try to compile

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[skip=0cm,list=true,labelfont=it]{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hptb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l l}
\subfloat[\label{fig:g1} Figura 1]
   {\resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics{img_a}}} &
\subfloat[\label{fig:g2} Figura 2]
   {\resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics{img_a}}} \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Figure caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

i get the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.14 \subfloat
[\label{fig:g1} Figura 1]
```

From the file log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian) (format=latex 2012.9.18)
Package: caption 2012/02/19 v3.2f Customizing captions (AR)
Package: caption3 2012/01/12 v1.4b caption3 kernel (AR)
Package: subcaption 2012/01/12 v1.1d Sub-captions (AR)
```

Any idea on what the problem might be?

Comment: `\subfloat` appears in the subcaption package just in an error message testing if it is defined and saying subcaption may mot be used with subfig. If you comment out the subcaption line and replace it with `\usepackage{subfig}` it runs without error, don't know what layout you intended though....

Comment: Thanks. That solved the problem (for now, at least, and that's what i needed)... See the comment to cmhughes for more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there's a bit of confusion here. The [`subcaption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subcaption) defines the `subfigure` environment, but the `\subfloat` command comes from the [`subfig`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subfig) package.

Personally, I'd recommend sticking with the `subcaption` package, and using a set up like the following for your MWE

[image: screenshot]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[skip=0cm,list=true,labelfont=it]{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hptb]
\begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img_a}
   \caption{First subfigure}
\label{fig:g1}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img_a}
   \caption{Second subfigure}
\label{fig:g2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Figure caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note that the `subfigure` environment takes a mandatory `<width>` argument, which I have specified as `.45\textwidth` (what you used in your MNWE). The `subfigure` environment can also take the same optional arguments that the `minipage` argument can take.

This now means that the `resizebox` command for your images should be used with `\textwidth` which will match the width of the `subfigure` environment.

Using this approach also means that you can remove your `tabular` approach.

Comment: You could simplify your MWE in two ways: First, you don't need the `\centering` statement since the two subfigures are spread apart as much as is possible. Second, instead of `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics{img_a}}`, it may be more straightforward to write `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img_a}`.

Comment: Yes. There was some confusion here. The problem is that i have a very large document (from where i got the MNWE) which compiled fine just a few months ago. The MNWE still compiles fine on a machine with an older TeX Live (2009). And that's where the problem came from...But thanks to you and David Carlisle for the quick and helpful solutions. I'll mark your answer as accepted, because i think it is better for new documents. But i'll go with David Carlisle suggestion, cause it is easier and quicker for a large existing document.

Comment: @Mico thanks a lot; you're absolutely right- have made edits :)

Comment: @joãogândara ok, no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[skip=0cm,list=true,labelfont=it]{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hptb]
\begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img_a}
   \caption{First subfigure}
\label{fig:g1}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img_a}
   \caption{Second subfigure}
\label{fig:g2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Figure caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This program prints 0.45 along with caption in caption of each figure

Comment: This program prints 0.45 along with caption in caption of each figure